# Different errors coming from different host values for mysql config in docker project

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm contributing to a new project, but getting info about the setup/build is difficult. I can get through these steps in the build process:

```
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev;
$ eval $(docker-machine env dev)
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up -d
```

The next command fails:

```
$ docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/python manage.py migrate
```

...with this error:

```
(2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (0)")
```

When I change the mysql HOST from `mysql` to `localhost`, I get a new error:

```
(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

I've read about each error, but the proposed solutions aren't relevant to my code (besides the suggestion of setting the `HOST` to `localhost`). Which host value is correct and what should be done about the respective error?

I'm not actually sure if `mysql` is running, where it *should* be running, and how to check its status.

Comment: can you paste the docker-compose.yml file here ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that mysql is in another container, and project container is called "web" in the docker-compose.yml.

When you change mysql to localhost it will attempt to connect to local mysql in the web container (via linux socket) but of course it doesn't exist, because it has it's own container which I suspect is called mysql in docker-compose.yml.

To view the running containers you can use `sudo docker ps`, if mysql container is stopped/restarting you can investigate using `docker logs <mysql container name/ID>`.

If thats the case, try to look for mounts in the docker-compose.yml to investigate further.

Comment: After I run `docker-compose up -d`, I can see many containers with `watch "docker ps"`. I notice the `mysql:5` image is restarting over and over without ever connecting and showing its `PORTS` values.

Comment: @JacobIRR So the mysql is not starting successfully, there you found your problem. Just use docker logs mysql to investigate the reason for those restarts. I suspect that in your docker-compose.yml you have volume mounts for mysql container that are not available.

Comment: Yeah there is a `volume` listed in the docker-compose file for this dir which has a permissions issue: `mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)` At least I have something to tweak now - Thanks for your help